# jQuery Function Implementation and Function Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference of calling function like:

`testCall: function()` and `function testCall()` in jQuery ?

**Update:**

***Questions:*** Does usage of one over the another have some performance issues related to it `OR` it really does not matter which one you are using ?

**Update 2**

Also other thing that I noticed that whenn I am defining function using `testCall: function()` and I call it using `this.testCall()` it works fine and am able to call it in any other function.

But when I am using `function testCall()` and I try to call it using `testCall()` in another function than I am getting errors and am not able to call it. Is this possible or there could be some other reason for the `errors` ?

Comment: Could you provide some example? The first one looks like `json` syntax and the last one is just regular syntax for function definition.

Comment: It looks like JSON syntax but note that one cannot include functions in JSON.

Comment: @Crozin: It's object literal notation (which JSON is a subset of).

Comment: @SO Reader: I would like to thank you all for providing continued guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example:

```
testCall: function()
```

`testCall` is now a function available on the object you're in, like this: `object.testCall()`  It can access other functions, properties, etc inside this object if it needs to.

In this version:

```
function testCall()
```

`testCall` is just a globally available method, not scoped to the object or plugin, whatever you're dealing with, you can call it from anywhere, like this: `testCall()`

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question about Javascript syntax (and semantics), not jQuery.

Both of those constructions define functions.  This:

```
var x = {
  // ...
  name: function() { /* ... */ },
  // ...
};
```

defines a function (an *anonymous* function) and assigns it as the value of the property called "name" in the object being assigned to the variable "x".

This:

```
function name() {
  /* ... */
}
```

defines a function with the name "name".  The effect is similar to:

```
var name = function() { /* ... */ };
```

but **definitely** different.  However, for most purposes it's safe to think about them as being *almost* the same. The effect is that "name" is bound to the function in the lexically-enclosing scope. If you do that definition outside of any other function, then "name" becomes a property of the "window" object, and the function is therefore globally available.  If that declaration is *inside* another function, then "name" is only available inside that function.

Usually you see the first form when you're doing something like setting up callbacks for some jQuery facility, like a UI plugin or `$.ajax`.  You're giving jQuery a function that it should call upon something happening — an AJAX call finishing, or a use action like a mouse click, or completion of some sort of animation.

**edit** oh, and finally here's another note.  If you define a function the second way, well then you can refer to that function by name and use it in an object definition (like the first example):

```
function globalFunction() {
  function localFunction() { /* ... */ };

  jQuery.something({
    x: 100, y: 100,
    callback: localFunction,
    // ...
  });
}
```

Many more such things are possible - functions are values in Javascript and can be tossed around as easily as numbers and strings.

Answer (score 0):

The first (`testCall: function()`) is *object literal notation* for defining a function and assigning it to a property on an object (not shown). The function itself is anonymous; the property it is bound to has a name, but the function does not.

The second (`function testCall()`) is a named function.

Named functions have several advantages over anonymous ones, and so though you see the first format quite a lot, I would recommend using it sparingly if at all. Named functions can be reported usefully by your tools (debuggers and the like), whereas anonymous functions just show up as `?` or `(anonymous)`. [More here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)

For that reason, rather than this:

```
function doSomeNiftyAjaxyThing(foo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "blah",
        success: function() {
            // Do something involving the successful result and `foo`
            foo.bar();
        }
    });
}
```

I would typically do this instead:

```
function doSomeNiftyAjaxyThing(foo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "blah",
        success: niftySuccess
    });

    function niftySuccess() {
        // Do something involving the successful result and `foo`
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Not only does this keep my code a bit cleaner (er, to my mind), but it means that if something goes wrong inside `niftySuccess`, I've given the function a name my tools can report to me. Note that other than the fact that the function has a name, they're identical – both functions are closures over the `foo` argument and anything else inside `doSomeNiftyAjaxyThing`.

You might be tempted to give the function a name inline, like so:

```
function doSomeNiftyAjaxyThing(foo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "blah",
        success: function niftySuccess() {  // <== change here, PROBLEMATIC
            // Do something involving the successful result and `foo`
            foo.bar();
        }
    });
}
```

There you're declaring a function with a name as an expression, and assigning the result of the expression to a property. Arguably you should be able to do that, but there are a series of implementation...anomalies in the various Javascript engines out there that prevent your being able to do that. (More in the article linked above, and in [this article](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/).)